package.el can't install lsp-mode and now can't upgrade packages anymore
I tried to install lsp-mode from MELPA, but get the following error message:
run-hooks: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, lsp-mode

So I thought I'd upgrade my other packages and try again, but now when I try to upgrade my packages, I get the same error message. Furthermore, if I look into my elpa folder, I see lsp-mode folder full of contents. If I delete that folder and try the installation again, I get the same message and the folder re-appears. Furthermore, I find a command lsp among the available commands, but if I execute it, it gives the same error message. What do I do now?

Use toggle-debug-on-error to get a backtrace when the error happens. Use that to find the broken hook function. Remove the broken hook function from whatever hook was being run at the time.

I used toggle-backtrace-on-error and got a message it enabled the mode globally, then tried installing again, but I still didn't get a backtrace. Can I get a backtrace specifically for that command, regardless of if it throws an error (because I think Emacs doesn't count the message as an error or something).

I found out the problem: for some reason a required lsp-mode file was not loaded when lsp-mode was called. Everything seems to work when that file is loaded manually.
